# Possible to make video responsive while having a max-width and max-height?

Tags: css, responsive-design, youtube

I am trying to place a video on my page, which has to be responsive (16:9 all the time). I found a lot of examples, which are basically the same (applying 56.25% padding at the bottom). However, as soon as I apply a max-height and max-width to the iframe (because I don't want it to fill out the entire page), the content underneath starts to move away (because of the padding).

https://jsfiddle.net/12npu2zu/

```
#video-container {
    position: relative;
    padding-bottom: 56.25%;
    padding-top: 25px;
    height: 0;
}

iframe {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    margin: 0 auto;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    max-width: 1000px;
    max-height: 563px;
}
```

Is there a way to keep it from doing that? The maximum width is 1000px and the maximum height is 563px (16:9).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Is this what are you looking for, i just wrapped all this in one more div and added same style.

```
<div class="video-holder">
  <div id="video-container">
      <iframe width="1000" height="563" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/U4oB28ksiIo" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen>        </iframe> 
  </div>
  <p>This should stay right underneath the video</p>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
 #video-container {
    position: relative;
    padding-bottom: 56.25%;
    padding-top: 25px;
    height: 0;
}

iframe {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    margin: 0 auto;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    max-width: 1000px;
    max-height: 563px;
}
.video-holder{
    display: inline-block;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    max-width: 1000px;
    max-height: 563px;
}
```

https://jsfiddle.net/326w5jqj/

Comment: Did you even try to resize the window? It overflows the window and doesn't even scale down. The text underneath just shoots away and is hidden.

Comment: DIV-ception. I need to add another DIV around them all just to get it to center as well. Funky. Works though, thanks!

Comment: Cheers! Glad I helped you.

Answer (score 0):

So what I ended up doing was placing a transparent image in the container. Then I applied this CSS to all the items:

```
#video-container {
    position: relative;
    width: 100%;
    max-width: 1000px;
    margin: 0 auto;
}

img {
    display: block;
    opacity: 0;
    width: 100%;
}

iframe {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    border: 0 none;
}
```

See it yourself: https://jsfiddle.net/12npu2zu/2/

Comment: The text moves to the left, when you increase the width dimension.

Comment: @Leon Yeah because the video is centered?